# Queryset for search by username and display_name In Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to search users by their usernames and display names.

- I have used that for the starting match.

```
search_obj = User.objects.exclude(user_uuid=token_user_uuid).filter(Q(display_name__istartswith=search_name)
                | Q(username__istartswith=search_name)
                ).order_by('-created_on')[:10]
```

I get the answer same as I want but the problem is if the display name is `William Welch` and I search for `Welch` It should return that user also, but it does not return that user.

```
cases.

username: 123William
display name: William Welch

if search_name 12 then match
if search_name 23w then not match
if search_name Wil then match
if search_name Welc then match
if search_name elch then not match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search with [**`__icontains`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) to look for a substring instead:

```
from django.db.models import Q

search_obj = (
    User.objects.exclude(user_uuid=token_user_uuid)
    .filter(
        display_name__icontains=search_name,
        username__icontains=search_name,
        _connector=Q.OR,
    )
    .order_by('-created_on')[:10]
)
```

If you want to search for starting words, you can work with a regex with the [**`__iregex`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#iregex):

```
import re

from django.db.models import Q

rgx = fr'\y{re.escape(search_name)}'

search_obj = (
    User.objects.exclude(user_uuid=token_user_uuid)
    .filter(
        display_name__iregex=rgx,
        username__iregex=rgs,
        _connector=Q.OR,
    )
    .order_by('-created_on')[:10]
)
```

Comment: That working but It's matching through anywhere in str. I'm trying to match from start. as I was using istartwith i work fine but if in display name has 2 words like `William Welch` so this matches only the first word it is not considering the second word.

Comment: @ZainJack: you can work with a regex in that case.